# How to get the the chosen image and show it on the same page using jquery ajax

Tags: image, jquery

I want to show the uploaded image on the same page without refreshing the page .

```
<form action='xyz.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='image' id='image'>
<input type='submit' name='ok' id='ok' value='upload'>
</form>

<div id='uploadedImage'></div>    

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ok').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         // then should be the jquery ajax call and response ?
         // help with this code . 

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot directly post this form via jQuery ajax as it is not possible to pass the file data with xmlHttp request. it requires to add some custom logic to use IFrame and set the form target attribute to that iFrame. by this way you can get the Ajax effect in place

Comment: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Comment: @KD see links that prooving you wrong

Comment: @KD : it is possible . That i know for sure . I am just stuck at the final step . And yes i am looking for the custom logic which make this work .

Comment: the solution ssilas777 will be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this jQuery File Upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Answer (score 0):

By standart means you can't (you can, but in two words you have to write many code with hiding inputs and showing buttons). But there are several good plugins you can use. You can check https://github.com/valums/file-uploader. It is open-code, so you can either use it or you can see how ajax upload is implemented

Comment: Being pedantic, those aren't two words :)